# Wordpress not sending email with Mailtrap

Tags: wordpress, mailtrap

I followed these instructions.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/phpmailer_init

Emails are sending and working for woocommerce, for example when I complete a purchase invoices are sent. But for some reason emails do not send when registering new users to the site.

Is there some log I can check in wordpress for this.

Update:
I only have this problem on localhost using Xampp. The real server seems to work fine.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can configure C:\xampp\php\php.ini and c:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini for gmail to send mail.

1. In C:\xampp\php\php.ini you can try to:

   Uncomment  'extension=php_openssl.dll'
2. Find [mail function] and change:

   SMTP=smtp.gmail.com smtp_port=587 sendmail_from =
   my-gmail-id@gmail.com sendmail_path =
   ""C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe" -t"
3. Open C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini and replace with

   smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com smtp_port=587 error_logfile=error.log
   debug_logfile=debug.log auth_username=my-gmail-id@gmail.com
   auth_password=my-gmail-password force_sender=my-gmail-id@gmail.com

Comment: Thank you I will check this tomorrow morning and let you know.